# HTML rendered by Rendertron is not including definition as clicking event

Tags: reactjs, seo, rendertron

I'm creating react app. For SEO practices, I decided to using Rendertron as follows.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron

It works returning rendered HTML by Rendertron, But I noticed button event doesn't working.

Doesn't Rendertron render content including event handling code ?

Do you have something idea ?

MetaInfo

React: ver16.8

Webpack: ver4

Rendertron(I stored it in EC2 instance)